# jQuery click event isn't firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

The relevant Javascript follows below, but in short, the archive button works while the delete button does not. I've already tried moving the event handler to a different file which the HTML calls using script tags to see if that makes a difference, but it doesn't seem to, although I'm unsure if it's broken in the same way. Additionally, the actual functions associated with each event handler are practically the same, so it seems reasonable to rule out that the function itself causes the problem. Why are the two buttons performing differently?

```
const mongo = require('mongodb');
const config = require('../../javascripts/config.js'); //databaseAddress can now be found at config.databaseAddress()const mongo = require('mongodb');
const MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient;

const url = config.databaseAddress();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar-userSearch').addClass('active');

    $('.archive-button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(-1)[0] ;
        console.log('id', id);
        var username = $('#username-' + id).val();
        var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
        var action = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];
        console.log('username', username);

        $.ajax({
            url: '/'+action+'/'+username,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {username: username, _csrf: csrf},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    addMessage(data.message, true);
                    if (typeof data.redirect === 'string') {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            window.location = data.redirect;
                        }, 2500);   
                    }
                } else {
                    addMessage(data.message, false);
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                addMessage('A network error might have occurred. Please try again.', false);
            }
        });
    });
    $('.delete-button').click(function() {
        console.log("stop pushing my buttons");
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(-1)[0] ;
        console.log('id', id);
        var username = $('#username-' + id).val();
        console.log('username', username);

        MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {

            const db = client.db("paxpopulidb");
            const id_query = {_id: id};
            const username_query = db.collection("users").find(id_query, {_id: 0, username: 1});
            const username = username_query.username;

            if (username) {
                if (username === "superadmin"){
                    console.log("You cannot delete the superadmin account.");

                } else {
                    db.collection("registrations").deleteOne(username_query);
                    db.collection("users").deleteOne(username_query);
                    db.collection("schedules").deleteOne(username_query);
                    console.log("Deleted " + username + " from database.");


    }}})
})});
```

The HTML uses Handlebars for templating and is as follows:

```
{{#each users}}
<div class='col-xs-12 col-ms-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-4 user-container tile-container' id='user-container-{{_id}}'>
  <div class='tile user-tile' name="user-{{_id}}" data-id='{{_id}}'>
    <div class='tile-icon' style='float: left'><img class='icon' src="/images/user.gif"></img></div>
    <div class='user-header tile-header'>
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target='#user-modal-{{_id}}'>
        <h4 class='tile-title'>{{#if fullName}}{{fullName}}{{else}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/if}}</h4>
      </a>
      <p class='tile-subtitle'>{{role}}<h class='small-text'>{{#if archived}}(archived){{/if}}</h></p>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="user-modal-{{_id}}" class="user-item-modal modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-messages"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-title">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          {{#if fullName}}{{fullName}}{{else}}{{firstName}} {{lastName}}{{/if}}'s Profile
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{> profileTable}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div>
    <input id='username-{{_id}}' type="hidden" value="{{username}}"></input>
    <input id='requestToken-{{_id}}' type="hidden" value="{{requestToken}}"></input>
    <input id='csrf' type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="{{csrfToken}}">
    <center>
      {{#isRegularUser role}}
          <button id='registration-button-{{_id}}' class='btn btn-info btn-hg registration-button'>View/Edit Registration</button>
          <button id='schedule-button-{{_id}}' class='btn btn-info btn-hg schedule-button'>View/Edit Schedule</button>
      {{/isRegularUser}}
      {{#ifNot archived}}
        <button id='archive-button-{{_id}}' class='btn btn-warning btn-hg archive-button'>Deactivate</button>
      {{else}}
      {{/ifNot}}
      {{#isRegularUser role}}
          <button id='delete-button-{{_id}}' class='btn btn-danger btn-hg delete-button'>Delete User</button>
      {{/isRegularUser}}
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

In short, the above makes a small box with appropriate buttons for each user depending on their role attribute, but the only working button so far is archive-button (no event handlers exist for the other two yet) However, the delete-button actually displays, it's just that clicking it does nothing.

Comment: You're missing all the closing brackets from your click handlers...

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll edit the code blocks. They're actually present in my files.

Comment: Is it dynamic? `$(document).on("click", '.delete-button', function () { console.log('yes'); })`

Comment: @epascarello If it were dynamic wouldn't both buttons be affected?

Comment: @Barmar it is a stab in the dark

Comment: @epascarello nothing is logged from that, so it doesn't seem to be dynamic

Comment: So sounds like it can not find the element by the class so you either have a typo or it is throwing an error and since it is a submit button it submits. See if you are finding elements with a simple console.log `console.log($('.delete-button').length);` . verify class names are spelled right. make sure no errors in console. Cancel the action or set type to button. Make sure your click handler is actually closed.  (Paste your real code into the question for syntax errors)

Answer (score 0):

Your bracketing is wrong. You have the delete button event handler inside the archive button click handler. So the delete handler isn't added until you click on an archive button (and if you click on archive multiple times, the delete buttons will execute their code multiple times).

You would see this if you'd indented your code correctly (every programming editor has options to automate this for you).

It should be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#navbar-userSearch').addClass('active');

  $('.archive-button').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(-1)[0];
    console.log('id', id);
    var username = $('#username-' + id).val();
    var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
    var action = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[0];
    console.log('username', username);
  });

  $('.delete-button').click(function() {
    console.log("stop pushing my buttons");
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').slice(-1)[0];
    console.log('id', id);
    var username = $('#username-' + id).val();
    console.log('username', username);
  });
});
```

Comment: in comments he mentioned the brackets are present in actual code

Comment: Then he edited the code to add them, and that edit showed that the brackets are in the wrong place.

Comment: yep, but I think you're right, if only one even fires there is something with syntax.

Comment: Tried this, still seems to not work (nothing logs to console after clicking the delete button).

Comment: Then you'll need to post a [mcve] -- show the output of handlebars instead of the template.

Comment: It seems like reverting to an older version solved the problem entirely, and as such I can't determine what exactly caused the error. However, console.log expressions did not actually produce any log output when I was testing, which is otherwise odd.